# meteor-jsdoc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: meteor, jsdoc

I am trying to set up meteor-jsdoc on an existing meteor project according to the steps here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-jsdoc

I am using windows and I run >npm install -g meteor-jsdoc , it is successfully

However when I try to run > meteor-jsdoc, it gives the error as in title.

I tried running the npm install both inside and outside the folder.

Anyone had the experience before? I am really stuck here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, re-installed git bash with unix tools option selected.